# Why is Flask route function not getting the correct variable changes from exec(open('pythonscript.py').read()?

Tags: python, exec

So, I have a flask route function like this

```
@app.route('/process_run', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_run():
   file_str_cnt = 0
   exec(open('pythonscript.py').read())
   
   return render_template('process.html', file_str_cnt=file_str_cnt)
```

pythonscript.py :

```
for i in range(10):
   file_str_cnt += 1
```

process.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Success</title>
</head>
<body onload="verify_parse()">
</body>
<script>
    function verify_parse() {
        confirm("file_str_cnt value "+{{ file_str_cnt|tojson }})
    }
</script>
</html>
```

When i run the flask app, the file_str_cnt variable is shown as 0 in the confirm pop up ( When it should really be 10). Any idea why the increments in the pythonscript.py is not affecting the process_run() function. If yes, Any way I can achieve this ? **(ALSO please note that: If I put the pythonscript.py script inside the route function without the exec() function, this will work. I want this to work with exec() function.)**

Answer (score 0):

`file_str_cnt` is a local variable inside your `process_run` function. Per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

Thus, you can fix your code this way (isolated in a self-contained example, it would be trivial to adapt to a route):

```
code = """
for i in range(10):
   file_str_cnt += 1
"""

def process_run():
    local_vars = { "file_str_cnt": 0 }
    exec(code, globals(), local_vars)
    return local_vars["file_str_cnt"]

print(process_run())
# => 10
```

or even

```
def process_run():
    file_str_cnt = 0
    local_vars = locals()
    exec(code, globals(), local_vars)
    return local_vars["file_str_cnt"]
```